# The output for "createHtmlOutputFromFile" is very literal and not utilizing the code I wrote

Tags: google-apps-script

So I wrote a script that has an HTML file associated with it. The script is long so I won't post it, but at the end I have this:

```
  // Send HTML content in email

  var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("AttendanceInfractionsHTMLTemplate").getContent();

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
    subject: 'EI Email',
    htmlBody: htmlBody,
  });
}
```

The problem is that when I receive the email in my inbox, the code in the HTML template hasn't run successfully and it shows the scriptlets in all their glory, such as my if/else statements and all that. This doesn't happen when I deploy a test of the HTML file. Any ideas? Can't seem to find anything about this in the Google Apps Script reference guide.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Use [templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) to evaluate scriptlets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`createTemplateFromFile()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createtemplatefromfilefilename) and [`evaluate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template#evaluate) it:

```
var htmlBody = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("AttendanceInfractionsHTMLTemplate")
  .evaluate()
  .getContent()
```